# How to print the first n lines of file?

Tags: python, readlines

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious and probably asked before but I can't seem to get the right combination of keywords together to give me an answer.

How can I write out the first n lines of a file (in effect, the opposite of `file.readlines()[0:10]`)?

e.g. I have a function that takes in an input file, and needs to process information from the latter part, throwing out a header. However I want to keep the multi-line header, to be put back in to an output file.

```
def readInfile(infile):

    with open(infile, 'r') as ifh:
        # Skip exta info at top of file
        header = ifh.readline()[0:10] # Keep the header for later?

        noheader = ifh.readlines()[11:]
        for line in noheader:
        # Do the useful stuff
            usefulstuff = foo()

return usefulstuff, header
```

Then later I want to write out in the format of the input file, using their header:

```
print(header)
for thing in usefulstuff:
   print(thing)
```

Is there a method I'm missing, or is `readlines` no good for this as it returns a list?

I assumed

```
for line in header:
     print(line)
```

would work, but it doesn't seem to in this case - so I must be doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

Why does trying to use `readlines()[]` twice fail for the second range?

I fixed the code as @pbuck pointed out, that the header line should have been `readlines()` not `readline` but now the `noheader` variable is empty? Do I really have to open the file twice?!

Comment: typo?... `header = ifh.readline()` should use `readlines()`, I think.

Comment: What do you mean here by not working. Is it giving an error or incorrect output? If error, then what is it or if incorrect output, then what is the current output and what it should be?

Comment: I was only getting a single lines partial output (and didn't spot the missing s so couldn't quite figure out what it was doing. Anyone know why calling readlines on a second range right after returns an empty variable, but the first readlines call is fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally, read first n lines, then stop.

```
def read_first_lines(filename, limit):
  result = []
  with open(filename, 'r') as input_file:
    # files are iterable, you can have a for-loop over a file.
    for line_number, line in enumerate(input_file):
      if line_number > limit:  # line_number starts at 0.
        break
      result.append(line)
  return result
```

Comment: This works pretty nicely for what I'm trying to do. I initially avoided 'hard-coding' it as I thought readlines would handle it fine.

Comment: This is just a complete example for easier demonstration. `readlines()` loads the whole file into RAM, which you might want to avoid. Reading line by line, as shown here, only loads the lines you actually need.

Answer (score 2):

Careful there, `readline()` returns a string, so `ifh.readline()[0:10]` is giving you the first few characters of the first line, and `noheader = ifh.readline()[11:]` gives you part of the next line.

What you could do is use loops like so:

```
header = ""
for i in range(10):
  header += ifh.readline()
```

Or as @pbuck suggests in their comment, use `readlines()` (note the s), which returns a list containing each line in your file, which looks more like what you were trying to do.

Comment: Ah well spotted, the **s** was indeed missing. That explains why I was only getting part of one of the lines. Thanks @pbuck et al.

Comment: Concatenating strings one by one is significantly slower than `str.join`. Also, a one-liner: `header = "".join(ifh.readline() for _ in range(10))`.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't two `readlines()` calls. Initially you call `readline()` which reads a single line from the file. Next you call `readlines()` and ignore the first 10 lines of the list it returns.

This would be a better way to do it:

```
def foo(lines):
    return ['foo: ' + line for line in lines]

def readInfile(infile):
    with open(infile, 'r') as ifh:
        lines = ifh.read().splitlines(False)  # read in the whole file, separate into lines
        header = lines[:10]
        usefulstuff = foo(lines[10:])

        return usefulstuff, header

usefulstuff, header = readInfile('name_of_file.txt')

for line in header:
    print(line)

for line in usefulstuff:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked on your solution and it seams you are on track. Consider this solution using mmap python package (https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) where you can treat the file as a string as well as a file. Here is my solution:

```
import mmap

def main(offset):
    with open("pks.txt","r+b") as fd:
        #Get the lines to skip
        try:
            skip=fd.readlines()[0:offset]
            lines=sum([len(x) for x in skip])
            rfile=mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(),0)
            rfile.seek(lines)
            print("Header: %s"%skip)
            print("Other lines:")
            line=rfile.readline()
            usefulStuff=list()
            while (len(line)>0):
                usefulStuff.append(line.lstrip()) #Remove new line
                line=rfile.readline()
            return usefulStuff,skip
        except TypeError as e:
            #Handle this error when offset is greater than the file length
            print("Error: %s"%str(e))
    return None,None
if __name__=='__main__':
    footer,header=main(3)
    print("Header: %s\nFooter: %s"%(header,footer))
```

Comment: `mmap` is great when you want to access arbitrary but known offsets in a file. Line boundaries are not like that.

Comment: @9000, yeah I did get that from the manual, though it will work in this case since we know the offset of the first few lines.